# variably modified at file scope -- C

Tags: c, linux

Bien, este es mi código:

```
/****** pru.c ****************************************************/ /**
 *
 * @file pru.c
 *
 * @brief Programa para comprobar el rendimiento del procesamiento de una
 * matriz con dos modos de ejecucion diferentes.
 *
 * Este programa lee de fichero una matriz de 1000*1000 elementos y la procesa
 * de dos formas, una por filas y otra por columnas, realizando una operación.
 * Para compilar en linux se usa: gcc -Wall -o pru pru.c -lpthread -lm
 *
 * @version 0.9
 * @author Jorge Martinez Hernandez
 *
 * @date 31-05-2016                                                   
 *                                                                         
 */ /***************************************************************************/

//using namespace std;

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>               ///< Funciones de potencia y raiz cuadrada
//#include <fstream>                ///< Para los ficheros de salida
#include <time.h>               ///< Usada para calcular el tiempo
#include <pthread.h>            ///< Sirve para crear los hilos

const int NUM  =          1000;  ///< Longitud del vector

/**
 * Datos compartidos por los hilos
 */
pthread_mutex_t m;                                          ///< Cerrojo para los hilos.
float matriz[NUM][NUM];                                         ///< Matriz de 1000*1000.
float v[NUM];                                               ///< Vector de test.
int ID_Hilo = 0;                                            ///< Identificador del hilo.
int num_Hilos;                                              ///< Numero de hilos.

int leerMatriz ()
{

     int ok = 0;
     FILE * f;

     if((( f = fopen( "datos.txt", "r" ) ) == NULL )){        ///< Si se produce error de lectura, no se continua
         ok = 1;
     }
     else{

     int columnas, filas;
     for (columnas = 0; (columnas < NUM) && (!feof(f) ); columnas++)
         for (filas = 0; (filas < NUM) && (!feof(f) ); filas++){
         fscanf(f, " %f", &matriz[columnas][filas]);           ///< Leemos un dato del fichero
                 }
         if ((filas != NUM)||(columnas != NUM))                ///< Esto quiere decir que no ha leido 1000*1000 elementos
            ok = 1;
     fclose(f);
     }
return ok;
}

void procesamientoFilas()
{
    int idHilo;                                             ///< ID de ESTE hilo
    int trozoActual;                                        ///< Punto donde estamos de la matriz
    int columnas, filas;                                    ///< Valores de filas y columnas

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);                                 ///< Bloqueamos el cerrojo para acceso exclusivo
    idHilo = ID_Hilo++;                                     ///< Anotamos el ID de ESTE hilo
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);                               ///< Desbloqueamos el cerrojo

    printf("Hilo procesamientoFilas con ID:  %d ha empezado...\n", idHilo);

    trozoActual = NUM/num_Hilos;                                ///< Anotamos cual es el trozo que toca procesar

    for (columnas = trozoActual*idHilo; columnas < trozoActual*(idHilo+1) && (columnas < NUM); columnas++)  ///< Usamos reparto consecutivo
    {
        v[columnas] = 0; 
        for (filas = 0; filas < NUM; filas++)
        {
            v[columnas] += pow(matriz[columnas][filas], 2); ///< Realizamos la primera operacion requerida sobre la matriz
        }
        v[columnas] = sqrt(v[columnas]);                    ///< Realizamos la segunda operacion requerida sobre el vector
    }   

    printf("Hilo procesamientoFilas con ID:  %d ha terminado\n", idHilo);

    pthread_exit(0);
}

void procesamientoColumnas()
{
    int idHilo;                                             ///< ID de ESTE hilo
    int trozoActual;                                        ///< Punto donde estamos de la matriz
    int columnas, filas;                                    ///< Valores de filas y columnas i j

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);                                 ///< Bloqueamos el cerrojo para acceso exclusivo
    idHilo = ID_Hilo++;                                     ///< Anotamos el ID de ESTE hilo
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);                               ///< Desbloqueamos el cerrojo


    printf("Hilo procesamientoColumnas con ID:  %d ha empezado...\n", idHilo);

    trozoActual = NUM/num_Hilos;

    for (filas = trozoActual*idHilo; (filas < trozoActual*(idHilo+1)) && (filas < NUM); filas++)    ///< Usamos reparto consecutivo
    {
        v[filas] = 0;
        for (columnas = 0; columnas < NUM; columnas++)
            v[filas] += pow(matriz[columnas][filas], 2);            ///< Realizamos la primera operacion requerida sobre la matriz
        v[filas] = sqrt(v[filas]);                          ///< Realizamos la segunda operacion requerida sobre el vector
    }

    printf("Hilo procesamientoColumnas con ID:  %d ha terminado\n", idHilo);

    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    time_t ini, fin;
    void * tipoProcesamiento;
    /**
     *Inicio del programa
     */
    if (argc != 3)                              ///< Comprobamos que se ha llamado correctamente al programa
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Uso columnas: pru num_hilos columnas\n Uso filas: pru num_hilos filas\n");
        exit(1);                                ///< En caso de que no, se dará un mensaje de error
    }
    /**
     * Carga e inicializacion de datos
     */
    if (strcmp( argv[2], "filas") == 0)         ///< Comprobamos si se pide la operacion por filas...
        tipoProcesamiento = procesamientoFilas;
    else if (strcmp( argv[2], "columnas") == 0) ///< ...o por columnas
        tipoProcesamiento = procesamientoColumnas;
    else                                        ///< En caso de que no se cumpla ninguna de las anteriores
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Uso columnas: pru num_hilos columnas\n Uso filas: pru num_hilos filas\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (leerMatriz() == 0)                      ///< Lee los datos de la matriz y en caso de que se lea correctamente, procede
    {
        /**
         * Procesamiento de datos
         */
        num_Hilos = atoi(argv[1]);              ///< Creamos tantos hilos como hayamos pedido en la ejecución

        ini = time (NULL);                      ///< Registro el tiempo de inicio

        pthread_t hilos[num_Hilos];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < num_Hilos; i++)     ///< Creamos los hilos
            pthread_create(&hilos[i], NULL, tipoProcesamiento, &i);

        for (i = 0; i < num_Hilos; i++)     ///< Espera a que se finalicen los hilos
            pthread_join(hilos[i], NULL);

        fin = time (NULL);                      ///< Registro el tiempo de fin
        /**
         * Muestreo de datos
         */
        printf("Tiempo de procesamiento para  %d hilo(s): %f", num_Hilos, difftime(fin, ini));
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No se ha podido abrir el archivo. Matriz no leida.");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El problema esta en las lineas siguientes:

```
float matriz[NUM][NUM];
float v[NUM];
```

Por alguna razón estas lineas me generan el siguiente error de compilación:

```
pru.c:36:7: error: variably modified ‘matriz’ at file scope
 float matriz[NUM][NUM];           ///< Matriz de 1000*1000.
       ^
pru.c:36:7: error: variably modified ‘matriz’ at file scope
pru.c:37:7: error: variably modified ‘v’ at file scope
 float v[NUM];              ///< Vector de test.
```

Estoy compilando en un sistema Linux con la siguiente linea:

```
gcc -Wall -o pru pru.c -lpthread -lm
```

Me gustaría saber cual es el origen del error y como podría arreglarlo. Dejo el programa completo para que se entienda todo, pero NO necesito una corrección del mismo. Solo quiero corregir ese error de compilación.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En C, declarar algo como `const int` no implica que ese algo sea constante sino únicamente de solo lectura. Es casi casi lo mismo pero no llega a ser exactamente lo mismo y es lo que le chirría al compilador.

En tu caso el compilador entiende que estás intentando crear estáticamente un arreglo de tamaño variable y eso no está permitido (al menos no de la forma en la que lo estás intentando).

Lo más sencillo sería sustituir `const int` por `#define`.

```
#define NUM 1000
```

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias @eferion, ha funcionado a la perfección. Si no es mucha molestia, podrías responderme una pequeña pregunta? Debo contar el tiempo para saber el rendimiento según cuantos hilos cree. Sin embargo no esta funcionando. Como podria hacerlo? Gracias

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "*no está funcionando*"?

Comment: Me refiero a que cuenta 0 segundos cuando debería dar un valor entre 0 y 1

Comment: ¿El programa tarda menos de un segundo en ejecutarse? Piensa que `time` no puede trabajar con más precisión